Why is my Visual Studio Code terminal not working
I can't write anything on the terminal of VS Code v1.88.0. This problem is from the v1.87.2 Windows 11
I am using Dart/Flutter.

I try to do everything as reinstall all SDKs and VS Code and nothing happened.
It was working before, but it stopped while using it and haven't work again. I tried to solve it by resting settings and turning the app compatibility off, and it still is not working

I'm actually using dart/flutter on VS Code v1.87.2 and Windows 11, and there's no problem on my side. Have you tried killing the terminal and opening a new one ?

Ensure that the shell path is correctly configured in Visual Studio Code. You can check and set it in the settings (settings.json).
